# C# WPF Clipboard.SetText() not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clipboard

I have encountered a problem while using the Clipboard in a WPF Application:
My code looks like this:

```
        var msg = "sample message for the clipboard";
        Clipboard.Clear();
        Clipboard.SetText(msg);
```

But only "\t\t\t\r\n" gets stored in my clipboard.
This is the only code that uses the Clipboard in my application and it gets called.

*Edit: Found the error. I used the above code for a copy-paste operation in a DataGridRow. This works for that:

```
 private void OnCopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
    {
            var msg = "sample"
            e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
            e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(new DataGridClipboardCellContent(e.Item, (sender as DataGrid).Columns[0], msg));
    }
```

I guess the problem was that it automatically tried to copy sth out of my DataGrid after my Clipboard.SetText(..) and overwrote my text again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearing the Clipboard is redundant as SetText does that automatically for you.

This is what I usually use:

`Clipboard.SetText(msg, TextDataFormat.Text);`

or

`Clipboard.SetText(msg,TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);`

Reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext)

Answer (score 4):

```
    protected void clipboardSetText(string inTextToCopy)
    {
        var clipboardThread = new Thread(() => clipBoardThreadWorker(inTextToCopy));
        clipboardThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        clipboardThread.IsBackground = false;
        clipboardThread.Start();
    }
    private void clipBoardThreadWorker(string inTextToCopy)
    {
        System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(inTextToCopy);
    }
```